# The getter 'auth' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: auth how can i resolve this error?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

So actually this my first time working with firebase as a backend i was building a note taking app and trying to access the authentication using email and password i was going throug a youtube video as i am new here and followed the steps of thid video [enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTYD13w6Duo&list=PL_D-RntzgLvY2tV7BK82UCZRyeDY21q-a&index=2)

**And my code goes somthing like this**

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:notepad/screens/firstview.dart';
import 'package:notepad/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:notepad/transitions/loading.dart';
import 'authentication/signup.dart';
import 'screens/home.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main(List<String> args) {
  // SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);
  runApp(
    NotePad(),
  );
}

class NotePad extends StatefulWidget {
  NotePad({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _NotePadState createState() => _NotePadState();
}

class _NotePadState extends State<NotePad> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider(
      auth: AuthMethods(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(primaryColor: Colors.white),
        home: HomeController(),
        routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
          '/signUp': (BuildContext context) => SignUp(
                authFormType: AuthFormType.signUp,
              ),
          '/LogIn': (BuildContext context) => SignUp(
                authFormType: AuthFormType.signIn,
              ),
          '/home': (BuildContext context) => HomeController(),
        },
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomeController extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeController({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final AuthMethods auth = Provider.of(context).auth;
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: auth.onAuthStateChanged,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            final bool signedIn = snapshot.hasData;
            // ignore: missing_required_param
            return signedIn ? Home() : FirstView();
          }
          return Loading();
        });
  }
}

class Provider extends InheritedWidget {
  final AuthMethods auth;
  Provider({Key key, Widget child, this.auth}) : super(key: key, child: child);

  @override
  bool updateShouldNotify(InheritedWidget oldWidget) {
    return true;
  }

  static Provider of(BuildContext context) =>
      (context.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType(aspect: Provider)
          as Provider);
}
```

**AuthMethods**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';


class AuthMethods {
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged => _firebaseAuth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
        (FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid,
      );

  // Email password signup
  Future<String> createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password, String name) async {
    final currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
        email: email, password: password);
    //user name
    var userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
    userUpdateInfo.displayName = name;
    await currentUser.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
    await currentUser.reload();
    return currentUser.uid;
  }

  //Email and password sign in
  Future<String> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
            email: email, password: password))
        .uid;
  }

  //sign out
  signOut() {
    return _firebaseAuth.signOut();
  }
}
```

**SignUp Page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:gradient_widgets/gradient_widgets.dart';
import 'package:notepad/authentication/textfield.dart';
import 'package:notepad/transitions/loading.dart';

enum AuthFormType { signIn, signUp }

class SignUp extends StatefulWidget {
  final AuthFormType authFormType;
  SignUp({Key key, @required this.authFormType}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _SignUpState createState() => _SignUpState(authFormType: this.authFormType);
}

class _SignUpState extends State<SignUp> {
  AuthFormType authFormType;
  _SignUpState({this.authFormType});
  bool isLoading = false;
  bool _obscureText = true;

  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      body: isLoading
          ? Loading()
          : Column(
              children: [
                Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 110.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                  child: Stack(
                    children: [
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          buildHeaderText(),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Form(
                              key: formKey,
                              child: Column(
                                children: [
                                  Column(
                                    children: buildInputs(),
                                  ),
                                  buildTextField(
                                    validator: (val) {
                                      return val.length > 6
                                          ? null
                                          : "Please provide a password more than 6 characters";
                                    },
                                    //controller: passwordTextEditingController,
                                    labelText: 'Password',
                                    obscureText: _obscureText,
                                    suffixIcon: IconButton(
                                      icon: Icon(
                                          _obscureText
                                              ? Icons.remove_red_eye
                                              : Icons.security,
                                          color: Colors.grey),
                                      onPressed: () {
                                        setState(
                                          () {
                                            _obscureText = !_obscureText;
                                          },
                                        );
                                      },
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(height: 70),
                          Container(
                            child: GradientButton(
                              increaseHeightBy: 10.0,
                              increaseWidthBy: 200.0,
                              child: Text(
                                'Sign Up',
                                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                              ),
                              callback: () {
                                //signMeUp();
                              },
                              //TODO: LOGIN KA CALLBACK JAYEGA YAHA PR
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                colors: [
                                  Color(0xFFFD7F2C),
                                  Color(0xFFFF6200),
                                  Color(0xFFFD9346),
                                ],
                              ),
                              shadowColor: Gradients.backToFuture.colors.last
                                  .withOpacity(0.25),
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10.0,
                          ),
                          Container(
                            child: GradientButton(
                              increaseHeightBy: 10.0,
                              increaseWidthBy: 200.0,
                              child: Text(
                                'Go Back',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              callback: () {
                                // Navigator.push(
                                //     context,
                                //     BouncyPageRout(
                                //       widget: LogIn(),
                                //     ));
                              },
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  colors: [Colors.white, Colors.white]),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
    );
  }

  List<Widget> buildInputs() {
    List<Widget> textFields = [];

    // if were in the sign up state
    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.signUp) {
      textFields.add(SizedBox(
        height: 50.0,
      ));
      textFields.add(
        buildTextField(
          validator: (val) {
            return val.isEmpty || val.length < 5
                ? "Please provide a valid User Id."
                : null;
          },
          // controller: userIdTextEditingController,
          labelText: 'User Id',
        ),
      );
    }
    //emailand password
    textFields.add(SizedBox(
      height: 30.0,
    ));
    textFields.add(
      buildTextField(
        validator: (val) {
          return RegExp(
                      r"^[a-zA-Z0-9.a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+-/=?^_`{|}~]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]+")
                  .hasMatch(val)
              ? null
              : "Please provide a valid Email Id";
        },
        //controller: emailTextEditingController,
        labelText: 'Email',
      ),
    );
    textFields.add(SizedBox(
      height: 30.0,
    ));
    return textFields;
  }

  Stack buildHeaderText() {
    Widget _headerText;
    if (authFormType == AuthFormType.signUp) {
      _headerText = Stack(children: [
        Text(
          'WELCOME\nTO,',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 45.0,
          ),
        ),
        Text(
          ' Note Pad',
          style: TextStyle(
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
            fontSize: 20.0,
            color: Colors.grey,
          ),
        ),
      ]);
    } else {
      _headerText = Stack(
        children: [
          Text(
            'HELLO,',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 65.0,
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            'Nice to see you back',
            style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 20.0,
              color: Colors.grey,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }
    return Stack(children: [
      Text(
        'WELCOME\nTO,',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 45.0,
        ),
      ),
      Text(
        ' Note Pad',
        style: TextStyle(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          fontSize: 20.0,
          color: Colors.grey,
        ),
      ),
    ]);
  }
}
```

**pubspec.yaml**

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  auto_size_text: ^2.1.0
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.6
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+10
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.1.2
  gradient_widgets: ^0.5.2
  provider: ^4.3.2+3
```

i checked my code more than twice i dont know what is causing this error i tried to add
 to this line of code

then i get a new type of error
saying  cant be added to this

the main error which i am getteing is this [image]

```
The following NoSuchMethod Error was thrown building HomeController(dirty):

The getter 'auth' was called on null.
Receiver : null.
Tried Calling: auth

The relevant error-causing widget was HomeController
When the exception was thrown this was the stack

#0 Object.nosuchMethod(dart:carepatch/object_patch.dart:5)
#1 HomeController.build.
#2 StatelessElements.build.
#3 Component Element.performRebuild.
#4 Element.rebuild

...
```

please see if anyone can help to solve this error

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Yeah i have edited the error agai see if you can do something

Comment: did u call await Firebase.initializeApp() ?

Comment: No i think i have added this line
 ```FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;``` where should i add this line. ```Firebase.initializeApp()```